# call function inside vb.net in winforms application when a user open a new tab in chrome

Tags: vb.net

I am using vb.net winforms applicationa and I need to call function inside my winforms applicatin  when a user open a new tab in chrome. is there any idea thanks,

Comment: You really need to update your question with a little more detail.  What is this function, where do you need to call it from?

Comment: Hursey,
I have a vb.net winforms applicationa and I need to call x function inside my winforms applicatin when a user open a new tab in chrome what I missed.

Comment: Simply, you've missed lots.  What's the goal here, what's this winforms app and function for, how is chrome connected, and is it just chrome or other browsers?  Is the browser inbedded in your win forms app maybe?  Is watching the process tree and triggering your function from there enough.  Repeating the question as a comment really clears up nothing

Comment: Dear Hursey,
we have 2 application one is a web application and the other is windows form from two different vender and the goal is when the web application open a new tab with a parameter then the windows form capture this param and then x function in winforms is fired ( supposed just to show this param in message) hope this will be clear.